# Xcode - build on Retina Mac with same output as on non-Retina Mac?

Tags: xcode, retina-display

When I build the current version of the SheepShaver classic-Mac emulator on a non-retina (2015) MacBook Air, and run the resulting output on a retina Mac, the text and graphics look sharp and clear.

When I build the same code on a retina MacBook Pro, and run the output on the MacBook Pro, the text and graphics are slightly fuzzy.

Is there a setting in Xcode (on a retina Mac) that would let me build as if for a non-retina Mac? I know I need to build with NSHighResolution set to "false" or else the contents of the SheepShaver window are 4x as large as the window itself, so that setting isn't answer.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The Retina-ness of the build Mac has no effect on how an app is built. There's some other difference. What versions of macOS are the two Macs running. What versions of Xcode?

Comment: That may be he issue: it's Xcode 9 (under High Sierra) on the non-retina MacBook Air; Xcode10 under Mojave on the retina MacBook Pro. I'll install Xcode 9 on the retina Mac and see what happens. Will report back later or tomorrow. Thank you for this comment.

Comment: I was able to test this - and yes, building under Xcode 9 in High Sierra on the same retina MacBook Pro produces the sharp text and fonts that I get when building under Xcode 9 on a non-retina MacBook Air. I don't have Xcode 9 installed under Mojave on yet, but will do that and experiment.

Comment: And now I was able to test this - Xcode9 under Mojave on a retina MacBook Pro produces the same sharp image that Xcode9 produces on a non-retina machine. So the display difference is between Xcode 9 and Xcode 10. I'll try to close this question and create another.

Answer (score 0):

This question is mistaken, as Ken Thomases points out. The different output is caused by the difference between Xcode 9 and Xcode 10. I've asked about this in another question:

[Get same graphic output under Xcode 10 as under Xcode 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348868/get-same-graphic-output-under-xcode-10-as-under-xcode-9)