# Get same graphic output under Xcode 10 as under Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, graphics, xcode9, xcode10

I build the SheepShaver emulator (which, in its current version, uses SDL2 to create and display its window) for use in macOS. When I build under Xcode 9, the fonts and graphics are sharp and clear; when I build under Xcode 10 (on the same MacBook Pro running Mojave), the fonts and graphics are slightly fuzzy. I use exactly the same code when building on both Xcode versions.

Is there a setting in Xcode 10 that will produce the same visual output that Xcode 9 produces? I've already got the Xcode 10 code using the Legacy Build System, because SheepShaver won't build under the new build system in Xcode 10. But I can't guess what other setting might affect this.

Comment: This is almost certainly not a build setting, exactly. As Apple changes the behavior of the frameworks as new versions of the OS are developed, they often keep the old behavior available in the frameworks for backward compatibility. The trigger for getting the new behavior is linking against the new SDK. It's assumed that you will update your code to account for the changed behavior as part of re-validating your app after such a significant change. In this case, the changed behavior is part of Mojave and apps only get it when linked against the 10.14 SDK. It's probably the view backing change.

Comment: See the [macOS Mojave 10.14 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_mojave_10_14_release_notes) and [AppKit Release Notes for macOS 10.14](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_mojave_10_14_release_notes/appkit_release_notes_for_macos_10_14).

Comment: Once again, you are absolutely right. The solution to this problem was to copy the MacOS10.3.SDK from a copy of Xcode 9 into the macOS SDKs folder in Xcode 10, and then change the Base SDK from "no SDK" to "macOS 10.13." The resulting build has the same graphic sharpness as a build made in Xcode 9. I'll be curious to know whether there's any way to bring the old view backing behavior under the current SDK - but I'm too much of a beginner to have any hope of figuring this out for myself (and I suppose it may be impossible).